# jasperreport in tomcat 9 and jdk 8

Tags: java, tomcat, jasper-reports

I am migrating from spring 4 to 5, and I had to upgrade JasperReport to 6.20.5.

Reports are ok on my local machine but when deployed as a war file on the real tomcat instance I am facing this issue

```
 ProgrammeSubreport.jrxml: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
1. Syntax error, static imports are only available if source level is 1.5 or greater
import static net.sf.jasperreports.functions.standard.LogicalFunctions.EQUALS;
```

it seems that the level of my JVM is not correctly identified.
Is there any way to configure tomcat with the correct settings?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try to remove the old version of `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler`